# Update column in table with value from another

Tags: sql, join, sql-update, advantage-database-server

I need to update one column called Ident in table a to be a value from table b, as shown below. Both the change and keep values in table b are valid Idents which will appear in table a. I need to find the Change value in table b in table a, and then change the value in table a to the Keep value in table b.

Statement i'm using is:

```
update p set p.ident=t.keep 
from pclscvq p inner join #tmp t on (p.ident=t.change) 
where t.change=p.ident
```

Table B:

```
Change  Keep
0004P   0004R
0004X   0004Y
00055   00056
00057   00058
0005B   0005C
0005K   0005L
0005Z   00060
00065   00066
0006X   0006Y
00070   00071
```

Very much stuck.
Using Advantage SQL

Comment: So what is your question? What have you tried already?

Comment: Ok, so i've got a temp table called #tmp (table b) with a column called "change" and a column called "keep". Both columns contain idents which exist in another table (table a). However, I need to change the ident value of table a to the value of "keep" in table b, where the "change" column in table b is the ident value of table a. Does that make more sense? I've tried: update p
set p.ident=t.keep
from pclscvq p inner join #tmp t on (p.ident=t.keep)
where t.change=p.ident

Comment: I've done that @Adosi

Comment: Edit your question to include `update` statement. Your join is on wrong field, BTW.

Comment: Cheers @Arvo. Should it be (p.ident=t.change)?

Comment: You should decide yourself :) With proper join you don't need where clause either.